# Show a popup in a table in Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular, popup

I have data in a table. Each data set has a button I can click to send its value back. When I click the button, I want to have a small popup display itself, like you can get here:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp

I tried this, as well as moving the div around in the table:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="message" [hidden]="booleanValue">Message</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Clicking my button used to display the message correctly, but it was not in a div, which meant that the table would have a row added, which was not what I was looking for.

Here is the CSS for the class message:

```
.message {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your angular codes?

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the example above to angular.

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/8AhWjA4c1c4uRiTA4gwH?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
 <td class="popup" (click)="setShow(5)">Click me to toggle the popup!
    <span [class.show]="pop===5" class="popuptext">A Simple Popup!</span>
 </td>
```